# Nichols chart grid for PGFplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, grids

So I have seen `smithchart` in the pgfplots library. I know that there is the `bodegraph` package, but for some reason, I don’t like the look of the grids, and prefer the original `pgfplots` over `bodegraph` (for some reason, I couldn’t get the plots from the `bodegraph` package to appear on TeXStudio). Is there a way to draw a Nichols chart **with the grid activated** or a pgfplots library that has it, just like the grid being on for `smithchart`?